# react on diagnostics (eg shutdown on low battery)

Tags: ros, diagnostics

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I saw the [diagnostics stack](http://ros.org/wiki/diagnostics), but is there a package that actually reacts on those diagnostic messages in terms of issuing a given message or shell command?

I'd like to shutdown the robot PC if the battery goes low (which the OS isn't aware of), and thought using `diagnostics` would be the right way.

Is there a prepared solution to that, or do I have to write a special node?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/32736/react-on-diagnostics-(eg-shutdown-on-low-battery)/) by [felix k](https://answers.ros.org/users/606/felix-k/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1650 on 2012-04-26

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

What I do on my project is have a backing message format (just a few strings and integers) to represent system state for things like power and temperature.

I then have a separate node that bridges these messages into the diagnostics message format, so that I can get a human readable log of robot diagnostics.

To make decisions based on battery capacity or state, I can use the backing message.

---

Originally posted by [mjcarroll](https://answers.ros.org/users/9/mjcarroll/) with karma: 6414 on 2012-04-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 6

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can use the [diagnostic_aggregator](http://ros.org/wiki/diagnostic_aggregator) with the [robot_monitor](http://ros.org/wiki/robot_monitor) to display that and other diagnostic information in a human-readable format. For hardware status monitoring, those packages are quite good.

The ROS diagnostic tools are for human notification (see: [REP-0107](http://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0107.html#best-practices)). Automatically shutting things down should probably be handled differently.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2012-04-26

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [brice rebsamen](https://answers.ros.org/users/597/brice-rebsamen/) on 2012-05-09**:
why use a separate channel? Why not create a not that would listen to the diagnostic messages, filter them based on their data, and take action when appropriate? I've read before that it's not recommended (maybe from you) but I can't see why. Could you elaborate?

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2012-05-10**:
I was merely paraphrasing the REP-0107 recommendation. The link to that document provides more details, with reasons.

**Comment by [felix k](https://answers.ros.org/users/606/felix-k/) on 2012-05-15**:
*When operating a robot being aware that all the parts are running correctly is important.* [REP] That's difficult when it gets to autonomous robots. Maybe the core problem is that *the diagnostics uses weakly typed information* [REP] that needs complex parsing no one really wants to do.

**Comment by [felix k](https://answers.ros.org/users/606/felix-k/) on 2012-05-15**:
The parsing could be skipped, though, when reacting solely on the level flag..